# Does the implication $x>1\implies x>1/x$ need to be proven?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does this seemingly evident fact,

> for $x > 1, (x > (1/x))$

need to proven?

Comment: Whenever you have to ask whether something needs to be proven, that usually means the answer is "yes it does"!  And if you can't immediately *see* how to prove it, this goes double.

Comment: Would the similar statement "for $x<1$, $x<1/x$" be just as evident?

Answer (score 9):

If you can't prove it immediately, then yes, it needs to be proven. Saying something is "self-evident" to get around having to prove it is just going to get you into trouble.

Comment: How does one go about proving this? Also, how does one go about proving 1 > 0? I believe you when you say self-evident statements still need to be proven. Now, I'm just curious how an even more "self-evident" statement would be proven.

Comment: +1.  Thomas Jefferson could get away with it, math students can't.

Comment: @Question [sometimes we start with axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Properties_of_ordered_fields) to avoid [having to provide proofs of "self evident facts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica)

Comment: Everything that can be proven is proven from definitions or axioms (which serve as the "definition" of the primative terms - since you cannot define them against even more primative terms, you "define" them by describing how they relate to each other). Several proofs have been offered, so I won't add another, but what constitutes a proof depends on what axioms you started with.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof:

Note $x>1\Rightarrow 1=\frac{x}{x}>\frac{1}{x}$. Putting it all together, we conclude $x>1>\frac{1}{x}$

In general, to prove this kind of statements, a "clever" multiplication/division on both sides is, sometimes, a useful trick.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \text{suppose      } x > 1 \implies   x \leq \frac{1}{x}$$
$$ x \leq \frac{1}{x}$$
$$ \implies x^{2} \leq 1 $$
$$ \implies x \leq 1 $$
$$ →← $$

$$ \text{so,  } x > 1 \implies x > \frac{1}{x} $$

Comment: Correct proof, save a very tiny detail. It is more precise to say, at the beginning, "suppose $x>1 \wedge x\leq \frac{1}{x}$" than what you wrote.

Comment: The first line of the proof I offered the asker is the title of this question.

Comment: Ah ok, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Follows from that fact that f(x)=(1/x) is decreasing for x>0. Graphically:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some of the most "obvious" facts are the most frustrating to prove (possibly because one is only asked to prove them when one has little to no experience with proofs, in the first place)! Thus, it is always better to assume that something needs to be proved, unless one already has the result from a previous proof.

Assuming that $x>1,$ we can prove each of the following from first principles (and, of course, use earlier points together with first principles to prove subsequent points):

- $x>0$
- $x^2>1$
- $\frac1x>0$
- $x>\frac1x$

**Added**: There are four more fairly crucial facts needed to prove that first point: $0x=0,$ $-1\cdot x=-x,$ $-(-x)=x,$ and $0<1.$ The last is often taken as an axiom, but not always. (Typically, it is only assumed that $0\neq 1,$ since otherwise all real numbers are equal.) Proof of the first is fairly standard: $$0=-(0x)+0x=-0x+(0+0)x=-(0x)+0x+0x=0+0x=0x.$$ Then (skipping some steps), we have $$-1\cdot x=-1\cdot x+x+-x=-1x+1x+-x=(-1+1)x+-x=0x+-x=-x.$$ Next (again skipping some steps), $$-(-x)=-(-x)+-x+x=-1(-x)+1(-x)+x=(-1+1)(-x)+x=0(-x)+x=x.$$ Finally, since the reals are totally ordered, we then must have $0<1$ or $1<0.$ But if $1<0,$ then $$0=1+-1<0+-1=-1,$$ so $$0=0\cdot-1<-1\cdot-1=-(-1)=1,$$ so $0<0,$ a contradiction.

I leave the rest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Past a certain stage of "mathematical maturity", of course you don't need to prove it – but you should prove it now. (See various comments and answers: if you have to ask, then yes.) For your own sake as well, so that you can *know* it's true and why, rather than assume it.

There are many ways to establish this, but among the most straightforward is by appealing to:
$$
\text{if } 0 < x < y \text{ then } 0 < \frac 1 y < \frac 1 x
$$
So if you have:
$$
0 < 1 < x
$$
you can conclude:
$$
0 < \frac 1 x < \frac 1 1 = 1
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. A question on it though: In your first line, isn't that kind of using what we're trying to prove in a way? If y is greater than a number x, than 1/y is less than 1/x. Why is _that_ true?

Comment: Oook good question, I have to say. Ultimately, to prove this, you have to chase it all the way back to the axioms for ordered field, and show that it follows from those. These define a set of elements of a "field" called the *positive" elements. An axiom states: for every $a$ in the field, $a$ is either positive, or 0, or $-a$ is positive. Another axiom says: if x and y are positive then so is xy. 1 is positive. If z is positive then so is 1/z (because provably, negative x positive = negative; and 1 = z(1/z) is positive). (cont)

Comment: (cont) The ordering relation is defined by: $x < y \iff y - x$ is positive. So (finally!): given $x > 1$, that means $x-1$ is positive. $1/x $ is also positive. So $\frac 1 x (x-1) = 1 - \frac 1 x$ is positive, which is to say, $1 > \frac 1 x$. @Question If you're curious, see the wikipedia article on [ordered fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field).

Comment: Hm, ok, I appreciate your responses.

Comment: Did that help or just make it worse? If you look at the wiki article, there's a section called "Properties of ordered fields" which lists the first generality I stated. I.e. it's something that follows readily from the axioms, an important general fact you'll be using again and again. So, as I said, prove it ... once ;) To do that, though, you have to know where the buck stops: what are the axioms? The article tells you.

Comment: Finally, I don't want to scare you:) Obviously you're proving something else entirely, and you just don't want to be challenged about "x > 1 => 1 > 1/x". Certainly you should *not* insert into your main proof all that gunk I just told you about ordered fields! Just state the rule you're using: "because x > 1, 1 > 1/x (proof on request)".

Comment: No, it didn't make things worse, I think the explanation helped.